# How to initializate a mat-slide-toggle of Material Design in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular5

I can't make the initialization of a mat-slide-toggle in a Reactive Form.

I have something like in the template

```
<mat-slide-toggle name="X" formControlName="X" color="primary"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

and in the controller I am doing

```
X:  new FormControl(true, [
      Validators.required
    ])
```

I have also tried with 1 or 0 or false instead of true but I didn't get it with a default value selected.

I would appreciate if someone could help me, many thanks.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-password-confirm play with this ;)

Comment: Thanks!!!, I didn't need the requiered tag for the validation. I thought I had to put it.

Comment: You can put it for sure. Don't have to ;)

Answer (score 11):

IMHO, there's some issue with your code. You should do something like this:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [formControlName]="X" [checked]="X.value" (click)="X.value =!X.value" color="primary">{{X.value ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}}</mat-slide-toggle>
```

And in controller you'll need to assign the `formControl` so, use `=` instead of `:` ie:

```
 X = new FormControl(true, [
      Validators.required
 ]);
```