# How to use mat-slide-toggle with FormControl?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840348/how-to-initializate-a-mat-slide-toggle-of-material-design-in-angular-5) it says that we should be able to do something like this:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [formControlName]="toggleControl">Slide</mat-slide-toggle>
```

However I'm trying that out in [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-slide-toggle-form-control?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and it generates the error:

> Error in src/app/app.component.html (1:19)
>   Type 'FormControl' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
>   Type 'FormControl' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It comes down to the way you are using the FormControl, when you use it inside a `FormGroup` you need to declare the form controls inside the form group using `formControlName`, like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="myInput">
</form>
```

But if you just need a single or simple `FormControl` you can just declare it like:

```
<input [formControl]="myInput"/>
```

This is your case, so just change your directive to `[formControl]` instead of `[formControlName]`:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [formControl]="toggleControl">Slide</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Comment: Hey I have this in my code but for some reason it breaks the tests
Any chance you can please look over this question and see if you know the answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77052899/error-while-running-tests-with-reactive-form

Answer (score 3):

Example:

.html

```
<form class="example-form" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" ngNativeValidate>

      <mat-slide-toggle ngModel name="enableWifi">Enable Wifi</mat-slide-toggle>
      <mat-slide-toggle ngModel name="acceptTerms" required>Accept Terms of Service</mat-slide-toggle>

      <button mat-raised-button type="submit">Save Settings</button>
</form>
```

.ts

```
export class SlideToggleFormsExample {
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = formBuilder.group({
      enableWifi: '',
      acceptTerms: ['', Validators.requiredTrue]
    });
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.formGroup.value, null, 2));
  }
}
```

source:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/gjjngpabxnlv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslide-toggle-forms-example.ts

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `formControlName="toggleControl"` instead of `[formControlName]="toggleControl"`. The error is gone.

You can also take a look at the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName).